# Is it possible to read permission of item using REST

Tags: rest

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to read permission of single item in a  document library using REST.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can try this below query to get all assigned permission of item :

```
https://{site Url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(1)/roleassignments
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to read the permission on single item.You can use following code for this : 
    'use strict';

```
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
var executor;

$(document).ready(function () {
    getCustomPermission();
});

// retrieve the hostweb url and appweb url from the query string
function getCustomPermission() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
        appweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );

        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getRoleAssignments);
    });
}

//make the rest call
function getRoleAssignments() {
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/
    items(1)?$expand=RoleAssignments/Member/Users&@target='" +
        hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
}

//display results
function successHandler(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var roleAssignmentHTML = "";

    var results = jsonObject.d.RoleAssignments.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        roleAssignmentHTML = roleAssignmentHTML +
            "<p><b>" + results[i].Member.OwnerTitle +
            "</b></p>";
        var users = results[i].Member.Users.results;
        if (users) {
            for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++) {
                roleAssignmentHTML = roleAssignmentHTML + 
                    "<p>" + users[u].Title + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
    roleAssignmentHTML;
}

function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerText =
        "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
        document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

For Reference : 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083176/Display-the-SharePoint-List-Item-Permissions-using

Comment: `/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items(1)?$expand=RoleAssignments/Member/Users` <-- This line doesn't work for several reasons. 1) If there's more than 1 RoleAssignment, you'll have to manually iterate through each RoleAssignment in the item via `/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/
    items(1)/RoleAssignments/GetByPrincipalId(...)/Member`. 2) If the PrincipalType for the RoleAssignment is a User instead of a SiteGroup, then the `Users` attribute is non-existent.

Comment: I repeat: "This line doesn't work for several reasons"